# The multiple of $26$ with the least digit sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I find a number which is a multiple of 26 with the least digit sum?

In the first 20 multiples 130 has the least digit sum of 4, But how do I find the one with the least digit sum out of ALL multiples of 26? also, every power of 10 comes back to a digit sum of 8.

how can I know there's not a 1000..0002 hiding somewhere, with a digit sum of 3?

My idea was maybe the digit sum of S(10a+b)=S(a+b) and that way I can only check the numbers 1-9 but this seems to work only when taking the digit sum repeatedly, until only one digit is left.

Comment: All multiples of 26 are even, so of course 2000...0001 is not a multiple. But the question remains, how do you know 1000...0002 isn't.

Comment: I could imagine a scenario where we decrease by much more than just $10$... Consider the number $1000000000-26 = 999999974$ and adding $26$ to this.

Comment: @JMoravitz Or for a more concrete example, $999...999\cdot26+26$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first (rather trivial observation) is that the minimal digit sum is unique, but the multiple that produces it isn't (just multiply by $10$). So we can't find a minimal multiple, just a sum.

It's obvious that there is no multiple of $26$ with a digit sum of $1$, since such numbers are just powers of $10$.

But, $$26\mid 10010$$So the minimal digit sum is $2$.

**Edit**: Since OP was curious, here's how I found the multiple.

I realized that if I could find a number with a digit sum of $2$ that is a multiple of $13$, I could just multiply by $10$.

WLOG I could assume that the units digit is $1$, so I simply wanted to find a power of $10$ which is equivalent to $-1\mod 13$. We know this exists since $10\in(\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z)^\times$. This happens to be $3$.

Comment: Is there an algebraic method to achieve $26\cdot385=10010$?

Comment: I'll edit in my approach to how I found the multiple

Comment: "since op was curious" lol that for a homework assignment.. thanks anyways, thats a very good way to think about the problem